# Can a pointer be placed on heap memory (C++)?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

I wrote some code in which I attempted to create a pointer on the Free store(Heap memory). I think it's impossible but I tried regardless.

The code below is basically creating a vector of pointers on the heap and then making those pointers in the vector point to some ints on the heap. I want to know if those pointers in the vector called vec are on the heap? I also wanted to know what is the proper way to free up space allocated  when using a vector like this. The last delete statement was crashing the program so I commented it out. I don't know if there is a memory leak.

```
    vector<int*> *vec = new vector<int*>();
    vec->push_back(new int(1));
    vec->push_back(new int(2));
    vec->push_back(new int(3));
    cout << (*vec)[0] << " " << (*(*(vec))[0]) << endl;
    cout << (*vec)[1] << " " << (*(*(vec))[1]) << endl;
    cout << (*vec)[2] << " " << (*(*(vec))[2]) << endl;
    delete (*vec)[0];
    delete (*vec)[1];
    delete (*vec)[2];
    //delete [] vec;
```

Comment: `//delete [] vec;` is Undefined Behavior you need `delete vec;` not `delete [] vec;`

Comment: `delete[]` is for matching `new[]`, which you never used. It's as simple as that.

Comment: You don't create pointers. A pointer is pointing to memory zones. These could contain objects, which indeed are constructed.

Comment: FWIW, you almost never want to do `vector<int*> *vec = new vector<int*>();`.  The vector itself will use dynamic allocation for the objects it holds, so you don't need to dynamically allocate the vector.

Comment: Each c++ suite has implementation details that may be unique.  My Lubuntu 18.04 64 bit, with g++ v7 reports sizeof(std::vector<T>) as 24 bytes, regardless of T, regardless of how many elements.  Your system std::vector<T> may be different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any variable can be created in heap, including a pointer. 
That said, at the C++ level you don't control where exactly the memory is created.

Comment: I was taught that when using heap memory, pointers are in stack and they point to variables in the heap. So I just want to clarify, pointers can be on the heap.

Comment: What do you mean  when you say at C++ level you don't control where exactly memory is created. I mean when you use new keyword, you know its on the heap.

Comment: ***So I just want to clarify, pointers can be on the heap*** Yes they can.

Comment: `c++` does not officially have a **heap** or a **stack**. Those are implementation details.

Comment: @timiz *I mean when you use new keyword, you know its on the heap.* Not exactly.  It is perfectly legal for a implementation to use a stack instead of a heap for dynamic allocation.  You use `new` to tell it you want dynamic allocation, but it is the implementation that decides where it actually puts the memory.

Comment: A pointer is a memory location that has an address to another location.  The location that stores that address/pointer can be anywhere in memory: Stack, Heap, Registers, I/O device, etc.

Comment: Your teacher has probably oversimplified things to a very common case where a local variable is created on the stack than contains a pointer to the heap (often the first example that is used when introducing dynamic memory allocation.)  One would hope that later, the concept would be further explained.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: "at the C++ level you don't control where exactly the memory is created"  vs  "you know its on the heap"   Using 'placement new' allows full control where, and does not need to result in use of dynamic memory.

Comment: You still don't know where the memory is created. Placement new creates the data in preallocated memory, but you don't know where this memory is.

The only way to know the memory is to inspect the pointer and somehow deduce it's not on the current stack, based on RSP comparisons. But this is useless.

Comment: In embedded systems, I have used 'placement new' and always knew where that memory was located.  Generally the target hardware had custom memory-mapped hw at that location.  The location was not dynamic memory. Nor was it automatic memory.  On one system, the hw was on a 32 bit bus, but system memory was 64 bit access with full cache.  I am ok with the idea that the memory was 'pre-allocated', but this was an implementation detail from hw developers, board designers (and not by software).

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing to understand about pointers is that there is nothing special about pointers.

Like all other vector elements, the elements of `vec` are located in the free store, since that’s where a vector keeps them.

If you want to manually create an `int*` in the free store, you would say `new int*`, which will of course return the address of that pointer, so for instance

```
int** pointer = new int*(nullptr);
```

However, there is very little point in doing this in practice — I don't think I’ve seen anyone use it in my twenty-odd years of C++.

Answer (score 0):

The c++ way of creating a pointer on the heap is as follows:
`int** pointerToPointer = new int*;`

The type `int**` can be read as a pointer to a pointer. Then we use `new` to allocate a piece of data of type `int*` (int pointer) on the heap.

Comment: _"The c++ way ..."_ Not really.

Comment: Why? The `new` operator is as low level as you can get as specified by the C++ standart. If you would use `malloc` then it would be the C way.

Comment: For that behalf yes. But in c++ there are way better mechanisms implemented. `new` and `delete` are considered as a last resort.

Comment: i.e. - modern C++ wants us to wrap our funky pointers into smart pointers or containers such that we should (almost) never need to use new/delete again.  Instead, let the scope of the object, its lifetime, handle this so that we don't leak memory everywhere while leaving dangling pointers.

Comment: I completely understand what you're saying, however I felt that good practices are beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allocate memory for an integer, you can say `new int;`, as you've done here.

The `new` keyword will accept any (non-void) type. So if you want to allocate for a pointer (which would be of type `int*`), you can just say `new int*`;

A (heavily contrived) example may look like:

```
int thing = 7;
int **ptr = new int*(&thing);
std::cout << "**ptr = " << **ptr << std::endl;
```

Notice that since `new` will return an address pointing to whatever type we allocated (in this case `int*`), we'll need to assign it to an `int**` variable.

---

All this being said, you're very unlikely to ever need to allocate a raw `new int*`. More than likely, you'd run into something similar if you're were dealing with dynamically allocated multi-dimensional arrays.

But in any of these situations, I'd *strongly suggest* using more modern memory management methods with [**Smart Pointers**](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers).